# Move bash function to another script

Tags: bash, variables

I have the following script:

```
Input=${SCHEMA_FILE%.gz}
Output=test_$Input
remove_fk
cat $Output > /tmp/output.sql
```

remove_fk is a funtion as follow:

```
   function remove_fk(){
    Temp1=1.sql
Temp2=2.sql
Temp3=3.sql
   
    cat $Input \
        | tr '\n' '\000' \
        | sed 's/\x00\x00/\x01/g' \
        | sed \
        -e 's/--\x00-- Name: \([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\); Type: TABLE; Schema: \([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\); Owner: [a-zA-Z0-9_]\+[^\x00]\+\x00--\x01CREATE TABLE \([^;]\+\)/CREATETABLE{\2}{\1}{\3 with (appendonly=true)}/g' \
        -e 's/--\x00-- Name: \([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]\+\); Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: \([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\); Owner: [a-zA-Z0-9_]\+[^\x00]\+\x00--\x01ALTER TABLE ONLY \(["a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\)\x00    ADD CONSTRAINT \(["a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\) PRIMARY KEY (\([^)]\+\));/PRIMARYKEY{\2}{\3}{\5}/g' \
        | sed -e 's/\x01/\x01\n/g' -e 's/\x00/\n/g' \
       > $Temp1

    
    sed \
        -e 's/--\x00-- Name: [a-zA-Z0-9_\$]\+; Type: INDEX; Schema: [a-zA-Z0-9_]\+; Owner: [a-zA-Z0-9_]\+[^\x00]\+\x00--\x01\x00CREATE INDEX \([^;]\+\)/-- CREATE INDEX{\1}/g' \
        < $Temp3 \
        | tr '\000\001' '\n\n' \
        > $Output
    }
```

As you can see, it seds a file ($Input) and generates an $Output file. The function does more sed than I just posted but for simplicity I just included bits of it. The main point here is that the function takes an input and creates an output.

I'd like to move this function to outside tha Main script, to clean up a bit the main script and not have many functions declared in a single .sh file..

I understand I should create a new .sh script (let's say remove_fk.sh), pass the 2 variables from the Main script and source this in the main one, but how I deal with the $Input and $Output variables so that they can be used in the main script later on? (see the cat $output to an sql file after removing fk keys). If I pass the 2 variables to remove_fk.sh, will they get modified and I can use them in the Main script? or Should I return the modified variables to the Main script?

Thanks,

Comment: `pass the 2 variables to remove_fk.sh` Just source the script, instead of running it. `will they get modified` You do not modify any variables in the `remove_fk` function, so why the need to protect against modifying it? The output I see goes `> $Output` to some _files_. Still would be better to use arguments from the start instead of global variables.

Comment: Thanks, so the actual $Output variable will have the content I need on the Main script once I call remove_fk.sh correct?

Comment: Well, do you understand what redirection operator `>` does? `$Output variable will have` The _file_ with a _filename_ equal to the _result_ of variable expansion `$Output` will have the standard output result of execution that second `sed | tr` pipeline. Ie. `Output=a.txt; sed ... | tr ... > "$Output"` would redirect the output to a filename named a.txt.

Comment: Also, you should quote your variables like `"$Input"` and `"$Output"`, except for a few circumstances. Read [this article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) for detailed information.